# Cannot see binded imges in VS 2012 at design time in WPF

Tags: wpf, xaml

I am using MVVM to bind images to my WPF page, but I have a lot of buttons and wihout pics, hard to determine button purpose. The problem is that VS designer does not show me binded images if I use such URI:

```
xAxis = new BitmapImage(new Uri("/SettingsManager;component/Icons/CameraIcons/X.png", 
UriKind.Relative));
```

But when I use:

```
xAxis = new BitmapImage(new Uri("../../Icons/CameraIcons/X.png", UriKind.Relative));
```

Designer correctly displays image.

I make binding via source:

```
<ToggleButton.Content> <Image Source="{Binding Source={StaticResource
CameraIcons}, Path=XAxis, Mode=OneWay,
UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"></Image> </ToggleButton.Content>
```

Does someone know why this happening?

Answer (score 0):

In your first example (that doesn't work), it looks like you provide an absolute URI, but declare it as `UriKind.Relative`.

In your second example (that does work), it looks like you provide a relative URI, and declare it as `UriKind.Relative`.

I assume *that* is why the first example work, but the second one doesn't. You could try using `UriKind.Absolute` instead in the first example.

Comment: I dont think so, because when I declare it as UriKind.Absolute, Designer stop showing ALL binded icons. If I set Relative or Absolute - other icons begin showing, but without that icon with "broken" path. May be there is another solution?